# Access Control comparisons of main languages

Tags: oop, programming-languages, access-control

I'm asking this question mostly off of curiosity and to have a good reference for this sort of thing, but can someone provide comparisons of access control hierarchies starting from class-level and moving up in some of the main OOP programming languages?

For example, in Swift it looks something like this:

```
Modules/Frameworks
|
|__Files
   |
   |__Classes
```

What about in C++, Java, C#, Python, Ruby, JavaScript, PHP, etc.? Feel free to add to that list or expand upon my current diagram for Swift. Also please edit this question or add tags if you feel it could be asked in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

### Swift

In Swift you have 3 levels of access control

1. `private`: only accessible from within the current `.swift` file
2. `internal`: the entire module
3. `public`: the entire world

### Java

1. `private`: only accessible within the current class
2. *no modifier*: like Private + the current package
3. `protected`: like no modifier + sublasses
4. `public`: the entire world

### JavaScript

Not provided, you cannot restrict the access to functions or variables.